# Can I use an output server as a new Input parameter in Shiny?

Tags: shiny

I am trying to use an output server as an input. I made up this app for showing what I want. In this example the user will enter two parameters, the number of rows and columns. The app is going to build a matrix with normal random values. The output is the Diagonal of the Matrix.

[image]

Can I use that diagonal values as a **selectInput()**? I have been seeking information about it, but I have not been lucky. Thanks.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Test app"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number rows and columns 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            numericInput(inputId = "Rows", label = "Enter the rows number",
                         value = 10, min = 5),
            numericInput(inputId = "Columns", label = "Enter the columns number",
                         value = 5, min = 5)

        ),

        # Show a DT table of the diagonal of matrix
        mainPanel(
           DTOutput("dt1")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to build a table
server <- function(input, output) {

    my_fun <- reactive({

        datos <- round(rnorm(input$Rows*input$Columns, mean = 48, sd = 1.5), 2)
        M <- matrix(data = datos, ncol = input$Columns, nrow = input$Rows, byrow = FALSE)

        list(diag = as.data.frame(diag(M)))
    })

    output$dt1 <- renderDT({

        my_diag <- my_fun()$diag
        datatable(my_diag, rownames = FALSE
                  , caption = 'Table 1: This is a simple caption for the table.')

    })


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, `updateSelectInput` can be used to update the choices of a dropdown / selectInput.

Here it is in action:

```
updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'Dropdown', label = "Select a Value:", choices = my_diag)
```

Here the full code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Test app"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number rows and columns 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            numericInput(inputId = "Rows", label = "Enter the rows number",
                         value = 10, min = 5),
            numericInput(inputId = "Columns", label = "Enter the columns number",
                         value = 5, min = 5),
            selectInput(inputId = "Dropdown", "Select a Value", choices = "")


        ),

        # Show a DT table of the diagonal of matrix
        mainPanel(
            DTOutput("dt1")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to build a table
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    my_fun <- reactive({

        datos <- round(rnorm(input$Rows*input$Columns, mean = 48, sd = 1.5), 2)
        M <- matrix(data = datos, ncol = input$Columns, nrow = input$Rows, byrow = FALSE)

        list(diag = as.data.frame(diag(M)))
    })

    output$dt1 <- renderDT({

        my_diag <- my_fun()$diag

        updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'Dropdown', label = "Select a Value:", choices = my_diag)

        datatable(my_diag, rownames = FALSE
                  , caption = 'Table 1: This is a simple caption for the table.')

    })


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```